# transform the content of relational table to the specified form using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database which contains the following columns:

```
key arg1 arg2 arg3 timebegin                     timeend
#1  a    b    c    1942-06-18 05:30:00+05:30     1945-06-18 05:30:00+05:30
#2  d    e    f    1940-10-09 05:53:20+05:53:20  1948-10-09 05:53:20+05:53:20
#3  w    x    y
```

The type of key, arg1, arg2, arg3 is character varying (255) and type of timebegin and timeend is timestamp with time zone.

Now I want to transform the relational table to the format given below:

```
<1> <a> <b> <c>                              //key,arg1,arg2,agr3
<2> <d> <e> <f>
<3> <w> <x> <y>
<1> <a> <b> 1942-06-18 05:30:00+05:30       //With columns containing time attributes just key, arg1, arg2, timebegin are copied.
<1> <a> <b> 1945-06-18 05:30:00+05:30
<1> <d> <e> 1940-10-09 05:53:20+05:53:20
<1> <d> <e> 1948-10-09 05:53:20+05:53:20
```

Is it possible to convert the relational table to the format given above using SQL. I know that one can dump the contents of a relational table into csv format. But is it also possible to transform the content of relational table to the specified form given above. My database is in postgres 9.1

**

*> EDIT: RULES:

> **1. First from all rows key, arg1, arg2, arg3 are copied and then 
>   2. For all rows containing NOT NULL timebegin and timeend values: key,arg1,arg2,timebegin and key,arg1,arg2,timeend is copied***

**

Note: It does not matter to me whether "<>" are placed or not.

Comment: It may be possible, but it may not be worthwhile.  What are the precise rules for your output format?  Would a non-relational intermediate program be appropriate here?

Comment: @DougM Yes a non-relational intermediate program would also do.

Comment: @DougM The precise rules of my output format is to convert: key, arg1, arg2, arg3 in one row and just add <> around each value. With rows in which timeBegin and timEnd is not NULL the output format is: key,arg1,arg2,timeBegin,timeend with <> placed around values of type charater and quotes placed along values of type timeBegin and timeEnd. Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: @DougM I have simplified the rules: 1. First from all rows key, arg1, arg2, arg3 are copied and then 2. For all rows containing NOT NULL timebegin and timeend values: key,arg1,arg2,timebegin and key,arg1,arg2,timeend is copied

Comment: I see little value in combining the output into a single denormalized set of tuples when you could simply select the distinct set of <a><b><c> into one set and <a><b><begin ts> into another. It's like you're trying to twist yourself into a human pretzel. To what end?

Comment: I've just noticed this question is tagged both MySQL and PostgreSQL. Which are you using?

Comment: @IMSoP I am using postgres. I have mentioned this in the question. Also since I am searching for an appropriate SQL query. Therefore, does it matter whether I am using MySQL or Postgres. Thanks for replying

Comment: @RoseBeck you want this transformation only to show right?
means you just want to show in this manner?

Comment: @RoseBeck Different DBMSes have different capabilities and behaviour which can make a difference to the solutions available, so yes, it does matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two key parts to this - assuming you absolutely must make this into an SQL query rather than some wider post-processing - are 1) selecting the appropriate columns formatted into a string in your preferred way, and 2) selecting all the results at once rather than running multiple SQL queries.

The first part requires cast your data to string types, and concatenating them together with appropriate separators. In PostgreSQL (and the SQL standard, but not all other DBMSes), the string concatenation operator is `||`. I also like the non-standard PostgreSQL syntax for typecasts, which is `column::type`, although `Cast(column as type)` will be more portable.

For the second part, you need the SQL `UNION` operator, which combines two result sets with the same number and type of columns. There are a few fiddly bits to remember - a `UNION` will remove duplicate rows, which can be avoided with `UNION ALL`; and you cannot directly use `ORDER BY` in the two queries being unioned.

Here is a sample query which seems to give what you want. Note that although this appears to sort correctly in the simple example, I think it should strictly have an `ORDER BY` at the very end, after all the results have been UNIONed together.

Interactive demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7f754/5/0

```
Select string
From
(
  Select
    '<' || key::text || '> ' 
    || '<' || arg1 || '> '
    || '<' || arg2 || '> '
    || '<' || arg3 || '>' as string
  From
    Foo
  Order by key
) as x

Union All

Select string
From
(
  Select
    key,
    '<' || key::text || '> ' 
    || '<' || arg1 || '> '
    || '<' || arg2 || '> '
    || timebegin::text as string
  From
    Foo
  Where
    timebegin Is Not Null
    And
    timeend Is Not Null

  Union All

  Select
    key,
    '<' || key::text || '> ' 
    || '<' || arg1 || '> '
    || '<' || arg2 || '> '
    || timebegin::text as string
  From
    Foo
  Where
    timebegin Is Not Null
    And
    timeend Is Not Null

  Order by key
) as x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation and for answering. I have an additional requirement which I am sorry I did forget to mention: When my inserted value are (1, 'a', 'b', 'c', '1942-06-18 05:30:00+05:30', NULL), (2, 'd', 'e', 'f', NULL, '1948-10-09 05:53:20+05:53:20') then I want <1> <a> <b> 1942-06-18 00:00:00+00
,<2> <d> <e> 1940-10-09 00:00:00+00

Comment: I tried to modify the above code but I am not getting as to how to do it

Comment: @RoseBeck Just only check `is not null` for the column you're retrieving in the `timebegin` and `timeend` selects, rather than both in both.